# A simplified application of Wigner's surmise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices

I am having trouble with this question,

Given the probability measure: $$P(M)dM = C |\lambda_1 - \lambda_2| e^{-\frac{1}{4}(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2)}d\lambda_1d\lambda_2d\theta $$

where $C$ is a constant and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. Show that the probability that $\lambda_1-\lambda_2 \geq S$ can be written:
$$K\int_{S}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4}se^{-s^2/8}\,ds $$
$K$ is another constant.

[image]

Comment: What is relationship between $M$ and $\lambda_k$ and $\theta$?

Comment: hi i've added the exercise for context